# Installing graphics driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have recently replaced my Windows 10 OS with Ubuntu 16.04. I have two graphics cards installed in my PC (Intel - built in and Nvidia - extended).

I would like to install graphics drivers for both graphics cards.

By default, the Intel graphics driver is installed.
I tried installing an Nvidia graphics driver using the official Graphics Drivers Team PPA.
I checked my system properties after installing Nvidia graphics driver, and it shows only the Nvidia.

How can I make both drivers available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a hybrid graphics card popularly known as Nvidia Optimus technology.

If you install the nvidia graphics card, you will still have the default intel graphics drivers. You can switch between the two from Nvidia settings.

[image]

Unlike Windows where it works dynamically, you need to switch between Nvidia and Intel from the Nvidia app then log out and log in for the settings to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are open source graphic drivers available for Ubuntu. 
By default Ubuntu uses the open source video driver Nouveau for your NVIDIA graphics card.
An alternative to Nouveau are the NVIDIA drivers, which are developed by NVIDIA. Nvidia xserver.

You will be notified to install additional drivers. If you aren't notified about additional drivers, you can do it yourserlf:

Go to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

Once the drivers are downloaded and installed, reboot your computer.